# How to set Sell price = Buy price * 1.01?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write a strategy.
I want the sell price is buy price *1.01.
e.g. If buy price is 50, the sell price is 50*1.01= 50.5

Below is my code :

```
strategy("test",pyramiding=1, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

rsi = rsi(close,6)  
ilong = input(23, title="period")
isig = input(3, title="signal")

bcwsma(s,l,m) => 
    _s = s
    _l = l
    _m = m
    _bcwsma = (_m*_s+(_l-_m)*nz(_bcwsma[1]))/_l
    _bcwsma

c = close
h = highest(high, ilong)
l = lowest(low,ilong)
RSV = 100*((c-l)/(h-l))
pK = bcwsma(RSV, isig, 1)
pD = bcwsma(pK, isig, 1)
pJ = 3 * pK-2 * pD

[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(close, 12, 26, 9)

plot(pK, color=orange)
plot(pD, color=lime)
plot(pJ, color=fuchsia)

bgcolor(pJ>pD? green : red, transp=70)

entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1)
sell_price = entry_price * 1.01
shortCondition = sell_price
longCondition = crossover(pJ,pD) and macdLine > -0.5

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=longCondition)
strategy.close("Buy", when=shortCondition)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set your take profit at 1%, use the `strategy.position_avg_price` built-in variable.

long_take_profit_price = strategy.position_avg_price * 1.01 // 1%
Then pass this variable to `limit` argument of your `strategy.exit()` call.

If, you really want to get find out the `buy_price * 1.01`, you can use `strategy.opentrades.entry_price()` built-in function to get the entry price.

```
entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1)
sell_price = entry_price * 1.01
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified it as below :
entry_price = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades-1)
sell_price = entry_price * 1.01
longCondition = crossover(pJ,pD)
shortCondition = sell_price

The error reason : Could not find function or function reference strategy.opentrades.entry_price

Comment: Upgrade your script to `v5`.

Comment: I added //@version=5 , but error msg : Could not find function or function reference 'rsi'

Comment: Because there are some changes going from v4 to v5. Better run the conver tool from the menu.